# Is there any requirements to do socket programming with WordPress?

Tags: functions

I have written following function in `functions.php` file and trying to access it through jquery ajax.

This works fine.

```
function data_fetch(){
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo "working";
}
```

But this doesn't show any error and prints nothing

```
function data_fetch(){
//  var_dump($_POST);
    echo "working";
    $host    = "x.x.x.x";
    $port    = 35001;
    $message = json_encode($_POST);
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
    $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  
    socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
    $result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
    echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
    socket_close($socket);
}
```

is this way right? if no then what are another way to do socket programming with WordPress?

Comment: There must be an error somewhere. Have you checked the web server logs?

Comment: in log it says that call to undefined function socket_create() but i have enabled sockets in my php ini file

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "No", there is nothing in wordpress that may interfere with usage of PHP socket API.